# Does the reduction of the dimensions over multiple layers allow more details to be stored within the final representation?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

From : https://debuggercafe.com/implementing-deep-autoencoder-in-pytorch/
the following autoencoder is defined

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()

        # encoder
        self.enc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=784, out_features=256)
        self.enc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128)
        self.enc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64)
        self.enc4 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32)
        self.enc5 = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16)

        # decoder 
        self.dec1 = nn.Linear(in_features=16, out_features=32)
        self.dec2 = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=64)
        self.dec3 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=128)
        self.dec4 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=256)
        self.dec5 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=784)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.enc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.enc5(x))

        x = F.relu(self.dec1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec5(x))
        return x

net = Autoencoder()
```

From the `Autoencoder` class, we can see that 784 features are passed through a series of transformations and are converted to 16 features.

The transformations (`in_features` to `out_features`) for each layer are:

```
784 to 256
256 to 128
128 to 64
64 to 32
32 to 16
```

Why do we perform this sequence of operations? For example, why don't we perform the following sequence of operations instead?

```
784 to 256
256 to 128
```

Or maybe

```
784 to 512
512 to 256
256 to 128
```

Or maybe just encode in two layers:

```
784 to 16
```

Does the reduction of the dimensions over multiple layers (instead of a single layer) allow more details to be stored within the final representation? For example, if we used only the transformation $784 \rightarrow 16$, may this cause some detail not to be encoded? If so, why is this the case?